# Data lost when updating iPhone app to new universal version

Tags: iphone, ios

I had recently created an universal app which was an iphone app only earlier, there were many version updates in that. I launched the universal app with next version that should be. But all the database data is lost when I update the old app to universal app.

Does anyone know how to avoid losing data during the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

When updating, the data is not erased (kept in the Documents directory), so there are chances that the reason of your data loss is in your code.